# How to make recyclerview each items have margin -5dp absolute image in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerView.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:id="@+id/photoRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

And It makes each item with **image_card.xml**

image_card has this layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/mindbox_bold"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cross_circle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want id `removeButton` goes on top overflowing id `imageCard` with marginTop and marginRight -5dp each.

But This shows result like below.

[image]

As you can see, `removeButton` is cut.

I want to make something like below in RecyclerView.

[image]

What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/mindbox_bold"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cross_circle" />

</FrameLayout>
```